# Check if the filtered list is empty (not null)

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this method using Java 8 streams to filter:

```
// Working code
public <T> List<T> myMethod(List<T> list) {

    List<T> resultList = list.stream().filter(element -> {
            // filter stuff functional method (lambda expression)
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return resultList.isEmpty() ? null : resultList;
}
```

I need to return straight away without make assignment to the "resultList", like this way:

```
// Working code
public <T> List<T> myMethod(List<T> list) {

    return list.stream().filter(element -> {
            // filter stuff functional method (lambda expression)
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

How can I use the following from the first snippet, in the second snippet. But I need to check if the result isEmpty, not null:

```
resultList.isEmpty() ? null : resultList;
```

For example, something like this:

```
// NOT-Working code - just an example from what I want to do
public <T> List<T> myMethod(List<T> list) {

    return list.stream().filter(element -> {
            // filter stuff functional method (lambda expression)
        }).collect(Collectors.toList()).
        // Something like this
        isEmpty() ? null : my_filtered_list; //Not working, just an example of what I need
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to return null if empty? Why not just return the empty list?

Comment: Avoid null wherever possible. If you have something which returns a collection, returning an empty collection is better than null in 99.9% of cases. A caller usually only cares about iterating over the elements of a list it gets back from such a function. For an empty list, that will no-op. That's almost always perfectly fine. If you return null, it's a NPE waiting to happen.

Comment: @all. Thank a lot for the quick response. I could return empty list but I thought that it could be better to return null just to handle better the return value of the list. That was just an idea. After that I needed to see how can I do it... I like deeping in details. I am just curious if this can be done.

Comment: If there is a good way to do in the return statement only this is good to know for extending my knowledge in java 8

Comment: You could use a Custom collector for this. Unfortunately the question is closed and I can not post an example here

Comment: @Lino can be simpler https://ideone.com/reg4Ps

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), l -> l.isEmpty()? null: l))` but as said by others, you should not replace empty lists with `null`. That’s not an improvement.

Comment: @Holger  Friend it is working nice and good. I will study the links the others posted here. I take as a good advice the comment about the null situation. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot all people who took part in this conversation helping me in the issue, although the closed the question!